# Bitcoin inheritance

Tags: wallet, multi-signature, inheritance-plan

For a while now I've been wondering what is the best way to setup an inheritance plan for the bitcoin I own. Has any one here set one up? What’s your plan?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, please check out the tag [tag:inheritance-plan] which collects exactly that topic

Comment: Thanks! Should have done more research before posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance plans very much depend on one's circumstances e.g. how accessible you want your Bitcoin to be whilst you are alive and how easy you want to make it for your descendants to access your Bitcoin when you've passed away. The easier you make it for your descendants the more you open up attack vectors for malicious parties. Designating a trusted individual who sufficiently understands Bitcoin technology and can assist your descendants certainly makes the process easier at the cost of reliance on that trusted individual.

Inheritance is discussed in Pamela Morgan's book [Cryptoasset Inheritance Planning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1947910116) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqiaJXtP4HI) I personally recorded recommending degrading multisig e.g. m-of-n that becomes (m-1)-of-n after x years as a strong option.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin companies that provide multi-sig services like Unchained also let your siblings take your bitcoin stack if you die and your siblings have at least 1 key in a 2 of 3 multi-sig setup which Unchained only holds 1 of 3 key.
Here is a link that might be helpful: https://unchained.com/blog/unchained-inheritance-protocol/

(Disclaimer: I'm an ex Unchained employee)